# How to assign a string value and then print the string with quotations

Tags: vb.net

I am attempting to assign a string value to a variable, and then I would like to print this assigned value with quotations, but I cannot figure out the proper syntax. An example of what I am trying to do is as follows:

```
Dim tU As String = String.Empty
    tU = "U"
    'How to print value of tU?>>>>should be "U"
    Console.WriteLine("""tU""")
```

I cannot figure out how to print the value "U" with quotations?

Comment: This question has been asked (and answered) many times before have you searched for an answer before posting?

Comment: I have updated my question to include more detail of what I am actually trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Console.Writeline("""U""")
```

or to print the value of a variable:

```
Console.WriteLine("""" + tU + """")
```

Comment: I have updated my solution to what I am actually trying to accomplish, I didn't add enough detail before! please excuse my mistake.

Comment: Console.WriteLine("""" + tU + """")

Answer (score 1):

Use Quotes twice like this `""`  .

So if you want to print `"HELLO"`

Just write `"""HELLO"""` :)

Comment: I have updated my solution to what I am actually trying to accomplish, I didn't add enough detail before! please excuse my mistake.